# I need take an id automatically from Opportunity object

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, lightning, soql

i create headless quick action. action generate and attach pdf.
i get id from this string
pdfPage.getParameters().put('Id', 'XXX');
I always need to enter the IDs manually, how can I automate the process so that the IDs are taken for all opportunities?

thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `recordId` in the lwc quick action.
Just define the `recordId` as a public property in your component.

I have updated your code
So it will look like this  :

```
@AuraEnabled
// Attach PDF on opportunity object

public static void savePDF(String recordId){
   try{
       PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference('/apex/newPageVf');
       pdfPage.getParameters().put('Id', recordId); // I need oppId from Opportunity object ***
       Attachment attach1 = new Attachment();
       attach1.ParentId = recordId; // I need oppId from Opportunity object ***
       attach1.Name = 'Test Attachment for PDF'; // I need Invoice_Number__c *custom auto_number field* from Opportunity ***   
       attach1.Body =  pdfPage .getContentAsPDF();
       attach1.contentType = 'application/pdf';
       insert attach1;
   } catch (Exception ex){
       system.debug(ex);
       system.debug(ex.getMessage());
       system.debug(ex.getStackTraceString());
       throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
   }
}
```

And JS :

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import savePDF from '@salesforce/apex/controllerTest.savePDF';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class HeadlessSimple extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    connectedCallback() {
        savePDF({recordId : this.recordId}).then( result => {
            const successToast = new ShowToastEvent({
                title : "Headless Quick Action!",
                message : "Headless Quick Action executed successfully.",
                variant : 'success'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(successToast);
        }).catch( error => {
            console.error(error);
            const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error',
                message: error,
                variant: 'error'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and help, but i can error in headless quick action. https://youtu.be/4Zai7NhWR7U

Comment: @Bogdan i have updated the answer (JS and Apex code).

Comment: thanks for your reply, error: https://imgur.com/a/Ml0l1nn

Comment: my full console log: https://youtu.be/GbkYxydt1j0

Comment: @Bogdan go to Developer Console and see log there , there must be stack trace string